# Data not getting added in SQL Database

Tags: android, mysql, sql

I am trying to make an app which requires storing data in an SQL Database which has 3 columns. The problem is data is not getting added in the database. I am using **getCount()** to see if data is getting added but it always returns 0.

My **DataHandler.class** is as follows

```
    public final class DataHandler 
{
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Context ctx;
public DataHandler(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
    mDbHelper=new FeedReaderDbHelper(ctx);
}
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "History";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME1 = "na1";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME2 = "na2";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_RESULT = "result";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + " ("+COLUMN_NAME_NAME1+ " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ COLUMN_NAME_NAME2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_NAME_RESULT + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public DataHandler open()
{
    db=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    mDbHelper.close();
}
public void Insert(String n1,String n2,int r)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_NAME1,n1);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_NAME2, n2);
    switch(r)
    {
        case 1:values.put(COLUMN_NAME_RESULT,"a");
                break;
        case 2:values.put(COLUMN_NAME_RESULT,"b");
                break;
        case 3:values.put(COLUMN_NAME_RESULT,"c");
                break;
        case 4:values.put(COLUMN_NAME_RESULT,"d");
                break;
        case 5:values.put(COLUMN_NAME_RESULT,"e");
                break;
        case 6:values.put(COLUMN_NAME_RESULT,"f");
                break;
    }
}
public Cursor returnData()
{
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME_NAME1, COLUMN_NAME_NAME2,COLUMN_NAME_RESULT}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

}

My Data Insert codes are-

```
   handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
                handler.open();
                handler.Insert(name1, name2, ans);
                handler.close();
```

And Data Query codes are-

```
    public class HistoryPage extends ActionBarActivity 
{
DataHandler handler;
int i,num;
String nm1,nm2,result;
private ListView mainListView ;  
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page);
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
    handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
    handler.open();
    Cursor c=handler.returnData();
    c.moveToFirst();
    num=c.getCount();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+num, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String[] Results = new String[4];
    for(i=0 ; i<num ; i++)
    {
        nm1=c.getString(0).toString();
        nm2=c.getString(1).toString();
        result=c.getString(2).toString();
        Results[i]=nm1+" & "+nm2+" - "+result;
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Results[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    handler.close();
    ArrayList<String> hstry = new ArrayList<String>();
    hstry.addAll(Arrays.asList(Results));
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.textv,hstry);
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just forgot inserting the data to the db.
You should put this line inside the insert() function:

```
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Comment: No problem, this kind of things use to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, first I do not even think that you have a database created.  Your Columns/Keys are. incorrect.

The proper way for designating a Column is as such:

```
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final int COL_USERNAME = 1;
```

Also your table create string is incorrect. The proper way is as such:

```
public static final String USER_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + " (" + 
    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    KEY_USERNAME + " VARCHAR UNIQUE, " + 
    KEY_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + 
    KEY_EMAIL + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + 
    KEY_FIRSTNAME + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + 
    KEY_LASTNAME + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " +
    "creation " + " DATETIME, " + 
    "lastlogin " + " DATETIME);";
```

Then you would build the table as so:

```
db.execSQL(USER_TABLE_CREATE);
```

Lets start with rewriting your Database Handler first and then go from there.

Also your insert data handler is functionally challenged.  No where are you saying where to insert the data.  For example here is a product insert handler:

```
public void addNewProduct(String cPRODUCTNAME, String cPRODUCTDESCRIPTION,
        String cPRODUCTCODE, String cPRODUCTCOST, String cPRODUCTPRICE,
        String cPRODUCTSTOCK, String cPRODUCTREORDER, String cTAXABLE,
        String cPRODUCTNOTES) {


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cvProduct = new ContentValues();
    cvProduct.put(KEY_PRODNAME, cPRODUCTNAME);
    cvProduct.put(KEY_PRODDESCRIP, cPRODUCTDESCRIPTION);
    cvProduct.put(KEY_PRODCODE, cPRODUCTCODE);
    cvProduct.put(KEY_PRODCOST, cPRODUCTCOST);
    cvProduct.put(KEY_PRODPRICE, cPRODUCTPRICE);
    cvProduct.put(KEY_PRODSTOCK, cPRODUCTSTOCK);
    cvProduct.put(KEY_PRODREORDER, cPRODUCTREORDER);
    cvProduct.put(KEY_TAXABLE, cTAXABLE);
    cvProduct.put(KEY_PRODNOTES, cPRODUCTNOTES);

    db.insert(PRODUCTS_TABLE, null, cvProduct);
    db.close();

}
```

The 2nd to last line states the Table to insert the data to, null, and then what values to insert.  In this case all of the above listed content values.

If you want to update instead of insert then you will simply add a WHERE claus and cahnge insert to update.

Comment: The difference in which I designated a column and the way you did, is just that you declared the string as private and I did public. Am I missing something?

Comment: absolutly.  KEY is a required Database word the same as COL_

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html This doesn't say so.

Comment: Do what ya like guy, but I do not think you even have a database let alone are inserting data into it

Comment: I have used SQL before, and I can assure you it worked without 'KEY'. And if Database isn't being created, why doesn't **.getCount()** get me a NullPointerException? It maybe Database isn't being created, but 'KEY'  is not the reason.